# python virtualenv ERROR: unknown command "config"

Tags: python, virtualenv

```
# virtualenv tmp/.venv

New python executable in /root/tmp/.venv/bin/python
Complete output from command /root/tmp/.venv/bin/python -m pip config list:
ERROR: unknown command "config"
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 793, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1087, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 935, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 964, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir
    config = _pip_config(py_executable, python_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1038, in _pip_config
    remove_from_env=["PIP_VERBOSE", "PIP_QUIET"],
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 886, in call_subprocess
    raise OSError("Command {} failed with error code {}".format(cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /root/tmp/.venv/bin/python -m pip config list failed with error code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `virtualenv` is picking up old version of `pip`. this is an issue with `vituelenv==16.3.0`, and downgrading to `16.2.0` fixes it. This is fixed in https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/1303 for future releases